# How to properly connect a VGA monitor to a video card with only DVI-D and Mini DisplayPort connections?

Tags: vga, hdmi, display

I just bought Sapphire HD 7990 GPU and I want to connect 3 monitors to it.

This card has 5 outputs: 1x DVI-D and 4x Mini DisplayPort.

I connected my two other monitors and they work great, but my third monitor doesn't work as expected. It is a 5-year old Asus TFT 19" 1440x900 monitor which ONLY connects via VGA.

The graphics card came with a bunch of adapters and I chose the one that was miniDP to DVI-I and then another adapter DVI-I to VGA but it doesn’t exactly work.

My PC recognises the monitor, its model number and maximum resolution but the monitor claims it receives no signal. The monitor works perfectly fine when connecting to other devices via VGA.

What cable/adapter should I buy or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Are you sure your Operating System supports more than 2 monitors? BTW I think the question is off topic for this stack.

Comment: My recommendation is to simplify. With MiniDP -> DVI -> VGA you may be losing signal. Try to connect the monitor to the DVI port using the adapter. I've been checking and it seems DVI-I and DVI-D are cross-compatible.

Comment: How are the other 2 monitors connected? Are they VGA as well? Or are you using direct Mini DisplayPort on them? I know this sounds stupid, but have you tried rebooting? One of the weird quirks I've found with Windows is when connecting new monitors, even though it recognizes it, you sometimes have to reboot before it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Mini DisplayPort is **digital only**.

DVI-I supports both ancient analog signal and modern digital signals. Converting the DP signal to DVI-D is easy, but it will only supply the digital signal on the DVI-I plug.

DVI to VGA can be easy if you convert the **analog** signal from a DVI-I or DVI-A connector to the VGA connector.

However in your case this signal is NOT present. You will need more than just a simple plug to 'convert' things. You will need an actual active component.

[image]

> What cable/adapter should I buy or is there anything else I can do?

No pure cable will work in your case.

You either need an active convertor which converts digital information to an analog format (which start around 30 euro and upwards) or you need to change to aa monitor which understands a modern format. (VGA is truly ancient. It only stayed around because unlike DVI and HDMI it had no extra license costs to equipt a monitor with VGA/DB15).

Answer (score 1):

For those who may read this question still nowadays:

It **is possible** to connect a VGA monitor to a DVI-D connector on a video card/motherboard **without an active part** contrary to [Hennes's answer](https://superuser.com/a/642392/1244517). I tried to find a solution to this problem too, and I found an adapter that is not more expensive than 8$/8€ nowadays. All I did was search on the web for `dvi-d to vga converter`, if I search for that now, I found Amazon sells it for the price mentioned. So I agree with [Doktoro Reichard's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/642390/monitor-connection-problem#comment804359_642390), and below is a picture of what I found that solves the problem (and I also use it).

---

**Update**: Fulfilling the request in [gronostaj's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/642390/monitor-connection-problem/1725522?noredirect=1#comment2666082_1725522): I didn't want to post a link because it may become outdated, but here is what I found (I don't live in the USA, but Amazon ships to many countries, though I didn't order mine from them): [link to adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D3XZ9SD)

FWIW, this is the first Google search result after the ads.

By the way, on the page I linked, it is stated that this adapter is an **active** adapter, I didn't know this part is working actively, I thought that an active part should be installed on the PC's motherboard to power it. All in all my model doesn't need anything else to power it but the DVI-D port on the outer interface of motherboard (the connector).

[image: DVI-D to VGA Adapter]

Comment: Can you post a link to the product? I'd like to take a look, but I'm apparently getting different search results.

Comment: I edited the answer to fulfill your request because the page doesn't allow such wordy comments like I write... 